# Display text box pop up when mouse hovers over icon on Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am working on a personal project where I need to get status of all devices within a unit. This status along with device name is returned in array from function `deviceStatus()`. If all the devices are `ON`, the home icon beside unit.id would turn green. If all devices within that unit are `OFF`, the home icon would turn red. This code works very well as shown below.

I am looking for help to display array returned from `deviceStatus()` as text box pop up when mouse hovers over the 'home' icon. I am very confused about `mouseover` event, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center py-2 px-2">
      <h1 class="display-1 unit-status m-0">{{ unit ? unit.id : null }}</h1>
      <font-awesome-icon
          icon="home"
          :style="deviceStyling"
          class="tab-icon mx-2"
          size="lg"
          id="unit-info"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  computed: {
    deviceStatus() {
      const device = this.unitDvc(this.currentSite.id);
      return device.map(dv => {
        const status = this.deviceStat(dv.device_id);
        return { name: dv.name, status };
      });
    },
    deviceStyling() {
      var turnedOn = null;
      var turnedOff = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.deviceStatus.length; i++) {
        if (this.deviceStatus[i]['state'] == 'on') {
          turnedOn = turnedOn + 1;
        } else {
          turnedOff = turnedOff + 1;
        }
      }
      if (turnedOn == this.deviceStatus.length) {
        return { 'color': `green` };
      } else if (turnedOff == this.deviceStatus.length) {
        return { 'color': `red` };
      }

    }
  },
</script>
```

Comment: You could do that very simply with the `title` attribute

Comment: You could use v-tooltip: https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-tooltip

Comment: Hmm, it seems pretty straightforward. Ive never worked with vue.js, but i guess first create a modal/ dialogue box whose state of showing would be triggered by mouseover event ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event ). Subsequently, you'd call the api/websocket connection to return the array data, which you can pass to modal itself. I guess this was a vue specific question, which I haven't used myself.

Comment: @HansFelixRamos I added v-tooltip.top-center="deviceStatus" to font-awesome-icon. This is certainly not the correct way to apply the function I realized and I am confused about this

Comment: @Sara I post an answer with my idea, I hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have installed the v-tooltip dependency

```
npm install --save v-tooltip
```

and added to your app

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip'

Vue.use(VTooltip)
```

Then you can add the directive to your component:

```
<font-awesome-icon
          v-tooltip="'Status is ' + deviceStatus.name"
          icon="home"
          :style="deviceStyling"
          class="tab-icon mx-2"
          size="lg"
          id="unit-info"/>
```

Comment: would it be possible to have v-for inside v-tooltip to display list of array elements?

Comment: You can put js code inside v-tooltip directive. Its better to create a computed or method to get the text you want display and then call it inside v-tooltip. e.g. v-tooltip="getDevices(listOfDevices)"

Comment: If you want to use mandatory v-for, you can use the component v-popover to create a custom content. see: https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#component

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using HTML and JavaScript, You could use the simple attribute of HTML i.e `TITLE`. It works simply as `mouseover` on that.

More Info: [Title - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)